# Set UID range for specific GUID

Tags: users, user-management, groups, useradd

I created some groups and I want to create some users to specific guid.

It will something like this:
group1 with uid from 1000 to 1500
group2 with uid from 2000 to 2500
group3 with uid from 3000 to 3500

If user1 is in group1 must have an uid from 1000 to 1500 (1002 for example) or if user2 is in group2 must have an uid from 2000 to 2500 (2001 for example) and so on with the rest of the new users.

Comment: I see intent and not  a problem to fix or a question to answer. To add a user to a group there is a command for but there is no procedure to enforce what you want, So why not start with a script in bash, python or even perl to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ubuntu `adduser` command creates a group by the same name when a user is created.   It uses the next available UID and GID for both if none is specified.

If you want to control the uid/gid curing creation, you can select them explicitly on the command line, but there is no automatic way to select ranges like you suggest unless you write your own adduser/useradd front end.